# ng-model not working with typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, undefined, typeahead, angular-ngmodel

I am using angular's typeahead, and running into trouble with ngModel.

Here is my typeahead html

```
<input
    type= "text"
    ng-model= "symbol"
    placeholder= "begin typing"
    typeahead= "hit.message for hit in getTypeAheadContents($viewValue)"
    typeahead-loading= "loadingSymbols"
    typeahead-editable= "false"
    typeahead-on-select= "onSelect($item, $model, $label)"
    typeahead-min-length= 2
    typeahead-wait-ms= 500
    class= "form-control" 
/>

<input ng-click= "search()" value= "Search!"/>
```

Here is the code in my controller (quite basic for the time being)

```
$scope.search = function(){
    alert($scope.symbol);
}
```

Now, the autocomplete code works as expected, but when I click the search button, I get the alert message "undefined"

What's even weirder is that I tried setting

```
 $scope.symbol = "";
```

at the beginning of my controller, and when I click the search button without typing anything into my typeahead, I get the empty string alerted back to me, as expected. However, when I DO type something into the typeahead and again hit search, I get back "undefined" once again. So clearly, angular's typeahead is not playing very nicely with ng-model, but I'm not sure what to do here.

Advice?

Answer (score 3):

Just set `typeahead-editable="true"` :-)

Comment: The default value of `typeahead-editable` is `true`.

Comment: But it was set to `false` in the html code of this question

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is still an issue for you. But I've tried the latest release of angularStrap (2.1.4) and with that I got it working when I set the ng-model to an object on which I set a property.

```
$scope.selectedPart = {}

      <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="selectedPart.part_id"
             data-animation="am-flip-x"
             ng-options="part.value as part.name for part in parts"
             placeholder="Selecteer onderdeel"
             bs-typeahead>
```

Somewhere in some function (could be a deep $watch)

```
console.log($scope.selectedPart.part_id)
```

Comment: I found a work around for myself, but thanks for getting back to me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question, but I sort of got around this issue by setting a different scope variable equal to the user's input inside the getTypeAheadContents function, and then using that variable (instead of 'symbol') inside the search function.